# Trying to convert JSON data to a JSON array in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, api

Hello im trying to convert some JSON data into an array, I have dont it this way before but without objects

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_day.geojson

Here is the code that gets the data and trys to convert it

```
public JSONArray getQaukes()
{


    String url = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_day.geojson";
    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

    try
    {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            Log.d("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jsonArray;


}
```

This is what i get
http://pastebin.com/HVnx3gsq

Anyone know how I could find the correct way to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As an example, if you were to extract "features" Array, then you should do it like that:

```
//First of all - create JSON Object which you are going to parse (deserialize JSON string)
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(entityResponse);
// Extract JSON array from Object
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("features");
```

Your JSON string has many different elements, that is why you need to create JSON object, then extract arrays from it and so on. Until the very last token.

```
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"metadata":{  
  "generated":1452461493000,
  "url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_day.geojson",
  "title":"USGS Magnitude 1.0+ Earthquakes, Past Day",
  "status":200,
  "api":"1.1.0",
  "count":128
},
"features":[  
  {  
     "type":"Feature",
     "properties":{  
        "mag":2.07,
        "place":"28km S of Gardnerville Ranchos, Nevada",
        "time":1452460963440,
        "updated":1452461071893,
        "tz":-480,
        "url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72578341",
        "detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72578341.geojson",
        "felt":null,
        "cdi":null,
        "mmi":null,
        "alert":null,
        "status":"automatic",
        "tsunami":0,
        "sig":66,
        "net":"nc",
        "code":"72578341",
        "ids":",nn00526227,nc72578341,",
        "sources":",nn,nc,",
        "types":",general-link,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,",
        "nst":8,
        "dmin":0.06765,
        "rms":0.11,
        "gap":197,
        "magType":"md",
        "type":"earthquake",
        "title":"M 2.1 - 28km S of Gardnerville Ranchos, Nevada"
     },
     "geometry":{  
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[  
           -119.751503,
           38.6351662,
           -1.8
        ]
     },
     "id":"nc72578341"
  },
  {  
     "type":"Feature",
     "properties":{  
        "mag":2.3,
```

In the extract above you have: "type" - JSON value, "metadata" - JSON Object, "features" - JSON Array and so on.

I recommend you looking into JSON syntax, so then you will be able to understand how to parse the data: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply, I will take a look at the syntax and try to convert the objects to arrays. :D

Comment: @ThatFellaNick look at the update in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was able to get all the data I needed! :D

Answer (score 0):

The result is a `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`.

Instead of `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);`

You should have `JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(entityResponse);`